# Why Pyspark filter function does not work?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to filter a dataset by order status. This is my code:

```
 df1=all_in_all_df.groupBy("productName") \
 .agg(F.max('orderItemSubTotal')) \
 .filter(col("orderStatus") == "CLOSED") \
 .show()
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'orderStatus' given input columns: [max(orderItemSubTotal), productName];
> 'Filter ('orderStatus = CLOSED)

Removing the `.filter()` helps displaying a result but I need to filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation restricts the number of resulting columns to the ones used for the grouping (in `group by` clause) and the result of the aggregation.
Thus, there is no `orderStatus` column anymore.

If you want to be able to filter on it, do it before the aggregation (but only filtered rows will be taken into account for the aggregation) or integrate them in the group by clause (again, the aggregation will be made by status, not globally, but in this second case you will have all statuses, with related aggregations, available).